# how to use condition in mRender : datatables php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, datatables

Hi I am using datatables ,I am getting record properly but from mRender I have 3 record. I want if condition is true then only it will be shown else not . But it not working.

Also how can I use if condition under anchor tag of it , I means like :

```
<a href="test_list.php?a='+full[20]+'&ab='+full[21]+'" class="click_'+full[22]+'">\n\
     '+full[20]+' - if (full[23] == 87 ) { '+ echo TESTER +' }  \n\  
</a>
```

Please note in above if condition "TESTER" is Defines a named constant

Below is format :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true, 
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "test_list_db.php",
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": [ 2 ],
      "mData": "null",
      "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {

                if(full[20] != 0 ){
                var status = '<div id="container">\n\
                        <a href="test_list.php?a='+full[20]+'&ab='+full[21]+'" class="click_'+full[22]+'">\n\
                        '+full[20]+' - '+full[23]+'  \n\
                        </a><br \>\n\  </div>';

                } else if(full[21] != 0){   //  -- if this record is ZERO then will not be seen 
               var status = '<div id="container">\n\
                        <a href="test_list.php?a='+full[0]+'&ab='+full[20]+'" class="click_'+full[0]+'">\n\
                        '+full[21]+' - '+full[24]+'  \n\
                        </a><br\>\n\ </div>';
                } else if(full[22] != 0){
               var status = '<div id="container">\n\
                        <a href="test_list.php?a='+full[0]+'&ab='+full[20]+'" class="click_'+full[0]+'">\n\
                        '+full[22]+' - '+full[25]+'  \n\
                        </a><br\>\n\ </div>';
                }
  return status;

      }
    } ]
  } );
} );
```

please let me know where is wrong and how to use that if condition under anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

you try consolde.log() or alert() to check that if or else if conditions are working properly anf compiler runing inner code of if and else-if, for example

```
if(full[20] != 0 ){
   var status = '<div id="container">\n\
      <a href="test_list.php?a='+full[20]+'&ab='+full[21]+'" class="click_'+full[22]+'">\n\
      '+full[20]+' - '+full[23]+'  \n\
       </a><br \>\n\  </div>';
   console.log(status);

}
```

after that check data in your browser console.

Comment: thanks for reply , as told i am getting first if condition as a result .. where is all my condition result are not zero , means it should return all but its only returning full[20]

Comment: i think its checking only if condition and return the value .. but if my else if condition is also true ..then it value should also be return .. but that not happening

Comment: if your if condition is true then only code inside if will run else and else-if code will not. you can change if condition like if(full[20] != 0 && full[21] != 0 ) and then change you else if conditions accordingly